# Linux Standard Base Compliance and Daemon Managment

Tags: linux

I am looking to control a number of processes across a variety of systems. My main problem is each system is not the same distribution of Linux. I was wondering if LSB, specifically the `status_of_proc()` function and a variety of other functions found in `/lsb/init-functions` is a viable means to this process. If not are there other standards I can fall back on.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap all of the components that you need to be able to control into LSB compliant init.d scripts then you should be able to use the same commands to control them from any LSB compliant linux distribution. The problem I found (and it may not be the case any more) was that the LSB functions were located in different places in different distributions. This meant that I couldn't easily just copy the scripts across to another distribution.

To check the status of running processes, I ended up falling back to a combination of pid files and the ps command. This allowed me to have the same implementation on each distribution and access to commands like:

service  start/stop/status